# NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = -1708

Tags: objective-c, applescript

I am trying to attach a Image to Mail application using Applescript. But on 10.5 I am getting

NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = -1708 error. What is this error means?

Can anybody guide me with this?

Regards,
Sowmya

Comment: We need way more information than that to help you. Working in pure Applescript (as in scripting an application with Applescript) will not return anb NSAppleScriptErrorNumber. That would only be found in working with Objective-C using Scripting Bridge or Apple Events.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an applescript that tells you what the error codes mean. Get it [here](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=30109). Look in post #9 for the most recent version I posted.

Answer (score 0):

As Philip Regan says. More info needed.

But I suspect its your construction of the file paths.
I have used NSAppleScript in the past to attach files to mail. If I remember right. My app gathered the files path as a Unix type path string.
i.e  /Users/UserName/Documents/myFile.ext.

And in the NSApplescript script string I use "POSIX file \"%@\") as alias"

```
NSString *scriptString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"set theMailname to (POSIX file \"%@\") as alias\ntell application \"Mail\"\nset newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties{visible:true,subject:\"%@\", content:\"%@\"}\ntell newMessage\nset visible to false\n\nmake new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:\"%@\"}\n  set theAddressFrom to \"%@\"\ntell content\nmake new attachment with properties {file name:theMailname} at after the last paragraph\nend tell\n save \nend tell\nend tell",fileStore,subject,body,theAddressTo,theAddressFrom];
```

**fileStore** being the unix type path of the file that is converted to an Alias.